# In Spring Data JDBC bypass @CreatedDate and @LastModifiedDate

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am using [Spring Data JDBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc).

I have an entity that has fields annotated with [`@CreatedDate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/CreatedDate.html) and [`@LastModifiedDate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/LastModifiedDate.html).

However, in some cases I want to set these two fields manually.

Is there a way to bypass `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` in some cases without removing the annotations from the entity? Or is there a callback that I can add before the entity gets saved?

Comment: Have you checked @PrePersist and @PreUpdate? https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events

Comment: @aksappy `@Prepersist` and `@PreUpdate` are JPA annotations and have no effect on Spring Data JDBC entities.

Comment: @aksappy I also don't want to modify the entity class if possible.
The `BeforeSaveEvent` did not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populating the auditing information is done by the [`RelationalAuditingCallback`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/core/mapping/event/RelationalAuditingCallback.java) and [`IsNewAwareAuditingHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.java).

The first one basically is the adapter to the module specific part (Spring Data Relational in this case) while the second modifies the entity.

You can implement your own variant of the `IsNewAwareAuditingHandler` stuff it in a `RelationalAuditingCallback` and register it as a bean. I did something similar a short time ago in [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow/tree/main/jdbc/auditing-with-template):

```java
@Bean
RelationalAuditingCallback isNewAwareAuditingHandler(JdbcMappingContext context) {
    return new RelationalAuditingCallback(new CustomAuditingHandler(context));
}

private static class CustomAuditingHandler extends IsNewAwareAuditingHandler {

    public CustomAuditingHandler(JdbcMappingContext context) {
        super(PersistentEntities.of(context));
    }

    @Override
    public Object markAudited(Object source) {

        if (!(source instanceof Product)) {
            return source;
        }

        Product product = (Product) source;
        if (product.createdDate == null) {
            product.createdDate = Instant.now();
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

Please consider the logic in the `CustomAuditingHandler` a place holder. There you should plugin your way to determine if you set the value manually. Maybe your entity implements an interface that offers that information as a transient field, or you store that information in a thread local variable.

Answer (score 0):

if u use above solution on spring boot, it ok. but in use `@EnableJdbcAuditing`, u should remove `@EnableJdbcAuditing`.
if it use that, `RelationalAuditionCallback` is dupulicated on ApplicationContext.

Here's a test based on @Jens Schauder's idea.
https://github.com/yangwansu/try-spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/src/test/java/masil/example/springdata/jdbc/ch9_14_1/ManuallySetupTest.java